# SQL: Join main-result and children

Tags: sql

I tried to merge two SQL-queries, but I failed.

The table has the columns "id, bid, data1, data2, data3, parent".

The first query will give me the id of the row and the data (selected by bid):

```
SELECT id, data1, data2, data3 FROM table WHERE bid = :bid LIMIT 1
```

This id will be used to get the data of all rows which are children of the first result:

```
SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM table WHERE parent = :id
```

As my result I need just data1, data2 and data3 for the main-part (query1) and all the children (query2) all together in one result...

I tried this one:

```
SELECT 
    main.data1 as data1, 
    main.data2 as data2, 
    main.data3 as data3
FROM table main 
LEFT JOIN table children ON main.id = children.parent
WHERE bid = :bid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the parent *and* children data, you must select both in the column list. Furthermore, you must qualify `bid` to come from either parent or children table. As a last part, using a `left join` selects also rows, which have no children

```
select p.data1 as p1, p.data2 as p2, p.data3 as p3,
       c.data1 as c1, c.data2 as c2, c.data3 as c3
from t1 p
join t1 c on c.parent = p.id
where p.bid = :bid
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4110/2)

---

I don't see a way to get the parent and child rows in a single query. What you can do is a union, which fetches the parent row in the first query and in the second part all the child rows

```
select p.data1, p.data2, p.data3
from t1 p
where p.bid = :bid
union
select c.data1, c.data2, c.data3
from t1 p
join t1 c on c.parent = p.id
where p.bid = :bid
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4110/5)

Comment: This nearly works. If I have 1 main result and 3 children, I will get a result with 3 rows with 6 colomns. But I want to geht 4 rows and three colomns.

Comment: Ok, so you want one row with parents data and three rows with the childrens data?

Comment: Yes. I want to get all rows, that means: The parent row and (if there are any) all the children rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT 
    main.data1 as data1, 
    main.data2 as data2, 
    main.data3 as data3
FROM table main 
LEFT JOIN table children 
ON main.parent = children.id
```